# How to completely remove Falcon door lock

Tags: lock

I'm trying to remove a Falcon door lock that was installed around 2007. I hope to replace it with a Nest x Yale lock. I don't know the exact model of the current lock. It doesn't look like Falcon makes this type of lock anymore, though this is the closest current model I could find: [Falcon MA series](https://us.allegion.com/en/home/products/categories/mechanical-locks/falcon-ma.html). I was able to remove half the lock. It seems that something inside is preventing me pulling the final piece out. See attached photos.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: remove the 2 screws above an below the handle shaft sticking out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For obvious reason the locks a build in such way that nothing can be unscrewed from the outside.

You removed all the screws you can find.

Now you need to unscrew the key cylinder from outside.
It should come out without resistance, but if you have to use players.

Comment: Unfortunately there are not. See the 3rd photo. I can't take the outside plate off...

Comment: I'll take another look tomorrow. Past my bedtime, lol

Comment: The screw heads will be down inside several of the five holes shown in the 2d photo. Probably not, however, the hole that's level with the retracted bolt.

Comment: That long thing is not the outer screw -- it is the cylinder retention screw that keeps the cylinder from rotating.  You can break the wrong key if you do it wrong, but usually the cylinders screw right into threads on the actual door, and that helps keep the outer plate attached.  The retention screw simply keeps you from unscrewing the cylinder.

Comment: @gbronner learning something new every day, I hope. Looking at the inside cover, from which hole did that retention bolt came from, counting from top.

Comment: @Ruskes #2.  Left side (closer to the cylinder) right above the rectangular deadbolt.  You don't need two screws -- the other one is there so if you flip the lock so it locks from the other side it will work there as well.

Comment: @Ruskes There's a d shape hole with circular side facing down on the edge (narrow side) of the door.  The two small holes below it are the retaining screws for the lock cylinder (see picture of lock cylinder in my answer below)

Comment: @gbronner thank you, found it

Comment: Thank you. I owe you a drink... The final step was turning the cylinder... After I took the lock off, I realized one of the extra holes requires a cosmetic cover and paint (since I'm retrofitting the Nest x Yale lock). On top of this, I tried screwing back the lock cylinder for 30 minutes to no avail... I think I'll have to call a locksmith to put the cylinder back on :(

Comment: It takes gentle touch to do that. or start turning to the left first then to the right, till you feel a slight slip. Keep doing left right till it catches the beginning of the tread.

Answer (score 0):

There's a retaining screw that holds the key cylinder in place -- you've already removed it.

Now put the key in the cylinder halfway (wrong key works better btw) and use it to unscrew the lock cylinder and remove it.  You should be able to pop the front face plate off.

Remove the handle and spindle, and then you should be able to pull the mortise lock out from the side.

Lock cylinders are threaded and screw into the mortise lock body sandwiched in the door frame.  The screws on the mortise body that go into the door frame simply keep it from rattling around too much and keep everything aligned.

The lock cylinder retaining screws slide into the cutouts in the lock cylinder and keep you from unscrewing it.

You may also have to remove the retaining screw on the outer door handle, but usually you can remove the outer door handle by pushing the shaft connecting the inner and outer door handles through the door.  Make sure that you keep the door from shutting after this, as you'll have a hard time opening it otherwise.

[image: Lock Cylinder example]

Comment: which way should the key be turned

Comment: It will turn the cylinder. It only is likely to go one way-- usually counterclockwise, but you might be able to get it to go clockwise a turn or two. 

Note that you are trying to turn the whole cylinder, not just the plug. That's why you keep the key halfway  out,  so the plug binds in the cylinder.